# What is status of efforts that were started during The Mess to create a new patform for some of the sites?

Tags: discussion

During the height of THE MESS there was enthusiam for creating a new platform, independent of SE, to which sites dismayed by the treatment of Monica, among other issues, could emigrate.

What is happening on this?  Did it fade away, or are some users working hard, underground, to make it happen?

I don't know how I feel about this; all I can say is that the aftermath of The Mess leaves me feeling blah.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 3 I know about,

1. https://topanswers.xyz/ Running on custom software
2. https://writing.codidact.com/ Running on Qpixel, if we **wanted  to migrate to this the door is open.**
3. https://codidact.org/ A planned version being build by mostly the same people as Qpixel with a goal of replacing Qpixel with better software.

Also, see https://discord.gg/7jf8UzS

Comment: Thanks, Charlie:  I signed on for writing/codidact, but it is not  a subject on which I can say much, mostly because it is geared towards fiction.

Comment: @ab2 if you would like to try setting up a new community on TopAnswers, you are very welcome to do so — we are working hard to keep improving things there every day and are already very capable of (mostly) full-featured Q&A and chat. I admit I don't know much about TGO and whether there are a significant number of people wanting to try starting something afresh though…

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I can't take on a  project of that magnitude.  Sorry. (:

Comment: Hiving off the (small number of) relatively active users on Writing:SE to another platform seems like it'll be the final nail in both of their coffins. Their activity wasn't stellar to begin with

Comment: @ab2 It would be possible to get a site setup like writing.codidact.com if we wanted to